# ¿Cómo crear una columna en un DataFrame sobre una condición que se da en otra columna?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Explico a fondo la pregunta, tengo por ejemplo el siguiente DataFrame:

Lo que deseo hacer es que si en la columna1 el valor que contiene esta celda es igual a 251, en esa misma fila pero en la columna3 el valor sea multiplicado por -1, en caso contrario que columna1 sea diferente de 251 pues la columna 3 no varia, intente con `np.where` pero no me funciono.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [250, "Elemento1","125"], 
                    [250, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [251, "Elemento3","-220"],
                    [251, "Elemento4","-275"],
                    [250, "Elemento5","500"]]),
                   columns=['Columna1', 'Columna','Columna3'])


df['Columna4'] = np.where[df1['Columna1']==251, df1['Columna3']*-1, df1['Columna3']]
```

Comment: Heee..... en primer lugar no tienes ningun elemento con el valor 251

Comment: Como no, Columna1, fila 3 y 4 el valor que contienen es 251

Comment: haa... perdon, estaba viendo el valor de la columna 3 >_<, ahora te doy una respuesta

Comment: Dale, mil gracias, apenas empiezo con Pandas y eso me tiene estancado, creo que lo podría hacer con listas de Python pero no sé si haya alguna forma mas eficiente de hacerlo. Aunque creo que ya lo logre con pandas, esperare tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayormente se usa el método `apply()` de pandas, el cual *aplica* una operación a nuestro dato, esto es como un ciclo `for` para los *DataFrame*. Este método recibe como primer parámetro una función que indica la operación a realizar con cada uno de los datos de nuestra columna, en este caso yo usaré un función lambda. Bueno lo único que tendremos que hacer es recorrer la `Columna3` de nuestro *DF* con el método `apply()` y el resultado guardarlo en la `Columna3` o donde quieras.

```py
df['Columna3'] = df["Columna1"].apply(lambda x: int(x)*-1 if int(x)==251 else x)
```

Se me olvidó mencionar que tienes mal la sintaxis de tu `np.where`, pues va con paréntesis y no con corchetes `np.where()` y con eso llegarias a la misma solución :D

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias y si, solo era ese problemita de sintaxis.